# How to use facebook API in my app

Tags: iphone

I am new to use Facebook  API in iphone app.I am trying to make an app where user can see updates ,online friends and send message to facebook friends etc.from iphone?
What should be the steps for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for use Facebook in iphone.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

And Reference links

http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-using-facebook-connect-for-iphone-part-1-of-2/

Comment: thanks. can u tell me which mac version .iso i have to download from torrent to run on vm ware ..can u send me link.

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook connect](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) is the library for you. This [facebook developer](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/) page might help. And [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app) blog post by Ray WenderLich is excellent..

Comment: thanks... i have asked chetan about mac os to download and to install on window 7 through vmware. according to you which is suitable? from which torrentz link i can download that?