# What is simplest way to implement facebook and twitter connect in iphone app?

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, twitter

I am creating an application and want to allow users to login using their facebook or twitter id. What is the fastest and simplest way to enable users login using their ids on these sites?

Any link to a tutorial will be of great help.

TIA,

Praveen S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754195/how-to-integrate-twitter-app-in-my-iphone/5754230#5754230) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752751/how-to-use-facebook-api-in-my-app/5752800#5752800)..Using facebook connect via graph api for facebook and use MGTwitterEngine for twitter are for me the most easiest and powerfull
 methods..

Answer (score 2):

Hii Praveen :

if u want your application for using sharing features , then try this toolkit where could make your work easy - http://www.getsharekit.com/